# How to reserve the public IP(static IP) to execute google dataflow job, so that I can whitelist the IP in source application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io, static-ip-address

I want to extract data from on-premise SQL Server database using google dataflow job,
so wanted to whitelist the dataflow VMs IP.
To whitelist IP at on-premise SQL Server need a static IP.
Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: My gut says that you won't get to use static IPs with Dataflow ... how many IPs should you have? Remember, there can be any number of workers.  What I think you could achieve is define your workers to have only internal IP addresses on a VPC network, setup a VPN and define routes to your SQL server through that VPN.  From your on-premises SQL server, all traffic will appear to come from the VPN which you can whitelist.

Comment: AFAIK Cloud Dataflow does not have the ability to assign a static public IP address. First, Dataflow can launch multiple instances, second, GCP does not offer the ability to reserve blocks of IP addresses for a service. Kolban's answer of using a VPN is a good choice for security.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding you question on how to whitelist your VM's IP addresses in you source application/provider, there is an approach that you can use VM as a NAT gateway or directly reserve an external IP address to your VM.

You can use one of the following options:

1. Create a Google Cloud Engine instance and a static **External IP** address, [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). In this case, you would have to configure all the external IPs manually. The path is: ***Compute Engine > VM Instances > Networking > Click in the pen under Network interfaces > External IP (drop down) > Create IP***.
2. Using NAT Gateway: according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway), **NAT Gateway**, in summary, helps users create complex networking scenarios by making changes to the routes collection. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) shows how to configure a **NAT Gateway**. It allows you to tag multiple VMs without IP addresses to the Gateways instance.

I believe both would suit your case. Please let me know if it helps.